# performance calculation in nested for loop

Tags: c, performance, optimization

```
  void row_order (){
    char A[1024][1024] = {0};
    char B[1024][1024] = {0};
    char C[1024][1024] = {0};
  

  for(int i = 0 ; i<1024;i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j<1024;j++){
      C[i][j] = A[i][j] * B[i][j];
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  for(int i = 0 ; i< 1000; i++){
    row_order();
  }
}
```

==> `C[j][i] = A[j][i] * B[j][i];`

By swapping the i and j variables in the C array, the performance of the code increases by 400%. What is the reason of this?
[[i][j]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sir1.jpg)
[[j][i]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0XTP.jpg)

Comment: You mean that it goes five times faster? How do you know this? Did you do about a hundred tests and do they all say the same? In similar circumstances? ...?

Comment: we did the tests and yes the results show correct.400% faster than other code snippet

Comment: It's not clear, which version is faster? `C[j][i]=...` or `C[i][j]=...`?

Comment: may be linked to where and how memory is accessed

Comment: Since you're array elements have type `char`, trying to access them sequentially means that you're reading and writing to the same word multiple times before moving on to the next.  If the characters being written are in different words, then it could be that memory writes are able to be done in parallel.  This is highly dependent on your machine architecture, and in any case this is very speculative (I haven't actually tried it).

Comment: It would be interesting to change the data type from `char` to `int` to see if the pattern changes.  If memory size becomes an issue, you might have to correspondingly reduce the dimension sizes to do the experiment.

Comment: From your snapshots, `[i][j]` costs 2s while `[j][i]` costs 8s, so the latter is worser than the former.

Comment: @TomKarzes I agree, this is probably related to your architecture and how it works with memory, different machines would experience different results.

Comment: @ILS is right... but OP said the opposite previously... Now the solution may just be the fact that [i][j] accesses cells one next to the other while [j][i] has to jump one j every time?

Comment: Now that it's clear that there is a difference indeed, which seems to be based on some caching-mechanism, does anybody know if this caching-mechanism is in place for all processors, all operating systems, all programming languages, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first case, `C[i][j] = A[i][j] * B[i][j];`, you access memory at near positions.

For instance, for `i=0`, and `j=0` and `1`, you will access
`A[0][0]`, `A[0][1]` which are near in position. So when CPU load `A[0][0]`, it has some chances to put in **cache** the values that are behind `A[0][0]`, `A[0][1]`, `A[0][2]`...

---

In second case, `C[j][i] = A[j][i] * B[j][i];`, you access memory at distant positions.

For instance, for `i=0`, and `j=0` and `1`, you will access
`A[0][0]`, `A[1][0]` which are distant in position. So when CPU load `A[0][0]`, it has no chances to load also the values that will be processed after

---

You can test it here: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##1VLBboJAEL3zFRMbG6jYrE17EduE9qQx7ckTJYYA6mwUmmWNaYy/Xjqza9G0xoO3EmCHmcebNy@TdudpWtdXWKTLdZbDoNIZlreLJ@eQ0rjKOYOFBlVupqXKcjVFCa4HWwfoSheJgjDqibv72L7hEbZiFxyqz2erL6erdM9K5XJjpKyAAHDAmAA7Hc/2/gHIPUBagGwAQOwYR5J5w310Q3pMZDXsHPuoXK9VAcznuddhJEhRDF2woYi9wNk5v3yQSD78ExtkTFMbG2zENpjovA09nv2PDcaHVYLFfg14TaYaKp0oTT34032djMcekzM2w0oHJ2eBByHobLQykorHy@YaGlLn0PGh6P@Z2xqOYJN89g2@38580xTaWfVetHyT9Y900ARGnBewpcxzUuxlCiU2Cht5o@Fl8sjduv5KZ8tkXtXdN/EN)

The behavior is the same with `int` (reducing the array sizes).

---

Some reading about cache :

- https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-memory-access-with-cpu-cache
- http://pld.cs.luc.edu/courses/264/spr19/notes/cache.html

---

Note that with `-O2` option, your code will be faster since it can be optimized, try to see it here  [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:11,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:11,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:11,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:11),source:%27%0A%0A++void+row_order+()%7B%0A++++char+A%5B1024%5D%5B1024%5D+%3D+%7B0%7D%3B%0A++++char+B%5B1024%5D%5B1024%5D+%3D+%7B0%7D%3B%0A++++char+C%5B1024%5D%5B1024%5D+%3D+%7B0%7D%3B%0A++%0A%0A++for(int+i+%3D+0+%3B+i%3C1024%3Bi%2B%2B)%7B%0A++++for(int+j+%3D+0+%3B+j%3C1024%3Bj%2B%2B)%7B%0A+++++++C%5Bj%5D%5Bi%5D+%3D+A%5Bj%5D%5Bi%5D+*+B%5Bj%5D%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++for(int+i+%3D+0+%3B+i%3C+1000%3B+i%2B%2B)%7B%0A++++row_order()%3B%0A++%7D%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cgsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O2%27,selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:12,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:12,startLineNumber:5),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: If you optimize the code, it should take 0 seconds to run, because the `row_order` function does nothing that's visible to the outside world, and will be completely removed.

Comment: @user3386109 yes, It's my point on the last link

Comment: would you share a link where I can find those infos about cache? I tried a quick search but I didn't find it

Comment: You say that there is a loss of performance due to different memory locations. but can that explain the 6 seconds in between?

Comment: @hasangkz When you read a value, the CPU will read a bigger memory area than necessary (it can't read just one byte). So when the CPU read `arr[0]`, the memory after `arr[0]` are stored in cache memory: `arr[1],arr[2]...`
In case your loop process the memory sequentially, the CPU don't have to read data from main memory, but from cache which is faster. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order